# ASP.Net MVC5 Ajax called Action for PartialView does not return response-content

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Scenario:**
I'm implementing a search function. The search value and some other values are passed to the controller with `AJAX` as soon as the user has stopped typing. The work is nearly done, it simply lacks the ability to display the matching results, because of the below described problem.

**Problem:**
The values are sent correctly to the action on the controller and the `PartialViewResult` object is generated correctly, meaning there is no exception thrown and it is not `null`. But the `AJAX`code does not receive any content.

[image: Screenshot debug with Chrome-Tools]

As you can see the server is returning the 200-HTTP-code but no content.

I would be glad if you can lead me to a solution. I have a feeling, that I'm missing something very trivial but I'm currently unable to detect the source of the problem.

**Code snippets:**

PartialView HTML:

```
<div id="GenericSearch_635749743014462375" class="col-md-12">
<div>
    <form id="genericSearchForm">
        <input id="genericSearchTextBox_GenericSearch_635749743014462375" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nummer, Name, usw." style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div id="genericSearchResults">
        <div class="list-group">
           <div class="list-group-item">
           <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">Keine Resultate gefunden.</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS AJAX:

```
function searchValue(searchId, value) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/Web/Search',
        data: {
            SearchUrl: '/Web/Search',
            JsonUrl: '/Web/GetJSON',
            SearchValue: value,
            ObjectType: 'Address',
            IsMultipleSelection: 'False'
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }).done(function(response, status, xhr) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders);
        console.log(xhr.error);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
    });
}
```

Action on Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
//[CustomAuthorizeAttribut]
public PartialViewResult Search(SearchSettings searchSettings)
{
    try
    {
        var filters = DefaultSearchFilter.DefaultFilters(searchSettings.ObjectType, searchSettings.SearchValue);
        var itemList = GetList(filters, new Sort(1, true), 25);
        var viewModel = new GenericSearchModel<T>
        {
            SearchResults = itemList,
            SearchSettings = searchSettings
        };
        //assigned to variable for easier debugging
        var viewResult = PartialView("_GenericSearch", viewModel);

        return viewResult;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Error(ex);
        return PartialView("_GenericSearch", new GenericSearchModel<T>
        {
            SearchResults = null,
            SearchSettings = searchSettings
        });
    }
}
```

Objects:

```
public class SearchSettings
{
    public string SearchUrl { get; set; }
    public string JsonObjectUrl { get; set; }
    public string SearchValue { get; set; }
    //Enum to determinate the type of the dto
    public ObjectType ObjectType { get; set; }
    public bool? IsMultipleSelection { get; set; }
}

public class GenericSearchModel<T> where T: IWebObject
{
    public SearchSettings SearchSettings { get; set; }
    public List<T> SearchResults { get; set; }

}
```

**Additional info:**

Note: The response of the action: `Search` has also no content if the URL is entered in a browsers address bar.

**Edit1:**
I just thought I should enable Visual Studios feature to break on every `CLR Exception` in the Debug -> Exceptions window. Now the first exception which is thrown is an `InvalidOpertaionException`, additional data:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type "GenericSearchModel'1[Address]", but this dictionary requires a model item of type "GenericSearchModel'1[IWebObject]".

To note: the address object is an implementation of IWebObject.

Now that I have the source of the problem, which entirely different to this questions meaning, I'm going with a different approach. Since I need to rethink that GenericSearch construct, there is no need to do further research on the initial issue (`AJAX` call is not receiving any response-content).

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside the controller action to ensure the action is actually being hit?  Could conceivably be a routing issue.

Comment: What does your GetList method returns? Can you post that code?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in the question, the action is invoked correctly else I wouldn't get a 200 response code in the calling AJAX code.

Comment: @freshbm It pulls some data from an api. Unfortunately I cannot post it's code here. It would be too much..

Comment: Can you try with the success() function instead of done() ? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @GiuDo I've edited my question about half an hour ago where i state that the problem isn't the ajax itself. Anyway, thanks for responding.

Comment: For Ajax you can also apply dataType : 'html'. However default content types are :xml, json, script, or html. 
But your error is different(dont see T defined in your controller code) and once you will fix that you will get result as expected.

Comment: @AnupamSingh It is defined, have `GenericBaseController<T> where T: IWebObject, new()`. The exception is thrown because the partial view expects a `GenericSearchModel<IWebModel>` but I'm passing in a `GenericSearchModel<Address>`. `T` becomes `Address` because the derived Controller is implemented as: `AddressController : GenericBaseController<Address>`.

Comment: then Address should be concrete class and as per error message Address should be like :
public class Address : IWebObject {}

Comment: @AnupamSingh It is. But you can't down cast an `Address` object into an `IWebObject` interface. I defined the type `T` on the view to be explicit of type `IwebObject`. I'm familiar with that problem but thinking about how to resolve it with a generic type gives me a headache. I'm now going for an entirely different approach. For example: replacing the `GenericSearchModel<T>` with a `List<Tuple<T1,T2,..>>` then I don't need to cast the `T` on the view. Thank you for your input.